# Hide <li> when href is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide

I want to hide any LI in .social-menu that have blank hrefs.

I originally had:

```
$('ul.social-menu li a[href*=""]').hide();
```

But it only hides the link.

I thought perhaps instead I could use:

```
$('ul.social-menu li a[href*=""]').addClass('hidden')
```

But it is not adding the class hidden.

The HTML is:

```
<ul class="social-menu">
   <li class="facebook"><a target="parent" href=""></a></li>
   <li class="twitter"><a target="parent" href="http://twitter.com/#!/dft_au">Twitter</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You need to use the `has` selector. your selector hides the `<a>` anchor only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to `.has`/`:has` which in my option is simpler and <s>most likely</s> more efficient would be `.parent()` (or `.closest("li")` if the `li` isn't the direct parent of the link):

```
$('ul.social-menu li a[href=""]').parent().hide();
```

(Also don't forget to use `href=""` instead of `href*=""`).

EDIT: It is much more efficient: http://jsperf.com/jquery-has-vs-has-vs-parent

Comment: Significantly faster it would seem!

Answer (score 6):

Use [the `:has()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) or [the `has()` method](http://api.jquery.com/has/) to select all `<li>` elements that contain an anchor (`<a>`) with an empty `href` attribute value:

```
$('ul.social-menu li:has(a[href=""])').hide();
// or…
$('ul.social-menu li').has('a[href=""]').hide();
```

Note that `.has()` is more efficient than `:has()`: http://jsperf.com/jquery-has-vs-has Although `:has()` is slightly more readable IMHO.

Comment: The performance seems to depend on the browser. My Chrome 18 executes the `:has` selector faster.

Comment: @RoToRa It also depends on the DOM structure. The one I’m using in my test case may differ from the one OP is using, and that may influence the results.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('ul.social-menu li:has(a[href=""])').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$('ul.social-menu li').has('a[href=""]').hide();
```

Comment: This will hide the `<a>` only. not the `<li>` see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I compiled this little [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NNhNy/) to illustrate your scenario. You are using the "contains" selector (*=), which means it's looking for an href containing nothing. Rather just explicitly test for an empty href by just using "=".

Answer (score 0):

```
listItems = ​$('ul li a');

$.each(listItems, function() {
  if($(this).attr('href') == '') {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  } 
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YZwRH/1/